# Why aren't my creases working?

Tags: modeling, edges

When I adjust the mean crease or weight crease nothing happens except the selected edges go purple. Why isn't it working?
[image: model in edit mode showing the creased edge]

Comment: There is nothing to crease, you need to extrude backwards

Answer (score 1):

You need more vertices to be able to crease the edge. When you make a crease, you are creasing a *seam* not a *boundary*. I have included an animated demonstration:

[image]

Comment: maybe default colors? i didn't realize what was happening till the third time through without the obnoxious pink of a crease.

Comment: @RadishoftheOpera Hmm . . . Good point.